# Racket: How can I fix my code so that it will return all the flipped pairs that is missing?

Tags: closures, racket, symmetric

This function  should return the symmetric closure of L.
Examples:

```
(Symmetric-Closure'((a a) (a b) (b a) (b c) (c b))) ---> '((a a) (a b) (b a) (b c) (c b))
(Symmetric-Closure'((a a) (a b) (a c))) ---> '((a a) (a b) (a c) (b a)(c a))
(Symmetric-Closure'((a a) (b b))) ---> '((a a) (b b))
(Symmetric-Closure'())---> '()
```

Here is what I have in Racket

```
(define (Symmetric-Closure L)
  ;Iterate over each pair in L
  (andmap (lambda (x)
             ;If the flipped pair does not exist in L, it will
             ;return L and the flipped pair that is missing. Otherwise, return L.
             (if(not(member (list (cadr x)(car x)) L))
                (cons (list (cadr x)(car x)) L)
                (append L)))
           L))
```

How can I fix my code so that it will return all the flipped pairs that is missing
For example, my code only return L and the last missing flipped pair (c a) instead of (b a) and (c a)

```
;this is wrong, it should return '((c a)(b a)(a a)(a b)(a c))
(Symmetric-Closure '((a a)(a b)(a c))-----> '((c a)(a a)(a b)(a c)) 
;this is correct
(Symmetric-Closure '((a a)(a b)(b a)(b c)(c b)))-----> '((a a)(a b)(b a)(b c)(c b))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`andmap` means "`map` the list using this function and then `and` together the results." In Racket, whenever you `and` together any values, the result is going to be either the last value provided to it, or `false`. For example, `(and value1 value2)` results in `value2` if neither `value1` nor `value2` is `false` (and if one of them is `false`, the result is `false` as well). Since the value produced by your `lambda` is never `false`, the result of your `andmap` is going to be the value of the lambda expression the final time it is called, which in this case, could be the list `(cons (list (cadr x)(car x)) L)` for the last value of `x` that it sees in the original list `L`. This means that all preceding values that were `cons`ed don't factor into the result at all.

You could modify this to use a simple `map` instead. But this produces a list of lists of pairs, not a list of pairs which is what you want. So at the end you need to flatten this to arrive at the result.

```
(define (symmetric-closure L)
  ;Iterate over each pair in L
  (apply append
         (map (lambda (x)
                ;If the flipped pair does not exist in L, it will
                ;return L and the flipped pair that is missing. Otherwise, return L.
                (if (not (member (list (cadr x) (car x)) L))
                    (list (list (cadr x) (car x)) x)
                    (list x)))
              L)))
```

One thing to be aware of, though, is that this algorithm calls `member` for every element in the original list. Checking for membership in a list is `O(N)` and you are doing this `N` times, meaning that the complexity of this algorithm is `O(N²)`. You should be able to do this more efficiently, for instance by using a [hash set](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28tech._hash._set%29).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how does "apply append" work?

Comment: `apply` allows you to pass arguments to a function as a list instead of directly. Eg. if you have a list of numbers `(list 1 2 3 4 5)` and you'd like to find the sum, you can't do `(+ (list 1 2 3 4 5))` directly (try it). But you can do it by using the apply function. `(apply + (list 1 2 3 4 5)`. To summarize, `+` is a function that accepts numbers as arguments, and `apply` allows you to provide those numbers in a list. Likewise, `append` is a function that accepts lists as arguments, and apply allows you to provide those lists in a list. Write down some examples and you'll get the idea.

Comment: @mindthief I would argue that it is almost never correct to `(apply append ...)` over a `map` when you can use a `foldr` with `cons` or `append` instead. Using `foldr` also grants you the ability to do filtering as well in the same step if needed.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer I am not sure how to use `foldr` in this case. When I change `map` to `foldr`, it says `foldr: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: at least 3
  given: 2
  arguments...:`

Comment: @RyanSchaefer I felt that discussion of `foldr` was outside the scope of the answer given the specifics of the question. While I wouldn't say that there's one "correct" way to do it, I encourage you to write up an answer using fold. I think it would be a useful contribution :)